# Parameter number 'X' is not an OUT parameter

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am getting the following error while accessing the DB,

```
 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
 Parameter number 3 is not an OUT parameter
```

Please see below the code

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = 
connection.prepareCall("{call ECommerce_GENAUTO(?,?,?,?)}");  
callableStatement.setString(1, orgId);
callableStatement.setString(2, tempCode);

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);               

callableStatement.execute();
setAutoGenrtdCode(callableStatement.getString(3));
setAutoGenrtdStatus(callableStatement.getInt(4));
```

Comment: So what does your stored procedure look like? Also, please pay more attention to formatting your question in future - you could easily have seen that half your code was scrolled off to the right in your original post.

Comment: Show your stored procedure

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, I figured out the reason of this error at runtime. Actually `procedure` file was not existed inside the database that is why i was getting the issue. I restored the `store procedure` file into my database and then it worked correctly.