# "Parameter is not an OUT parameter" error while calling stored procedure via CallableStatement

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, callable-statement

I have been trying call procedure "proc" which were created in MySQL Workbanch:

```
create database test_database;
use test_database;

delimiter &&
create procedure proc(inout param INT UNSIGNED)
begin
    set param = 2*param;
end&&
```

using this application :

```
package test;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1", "root", "root");
        connection.createStatement().execute("USE test_database");
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call proc(?)}");
        callableStatement.setInt(1, 5);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        ResultSet result = callableStatement.executeQuery();
        if (result.first()) {
            System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
        }            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

but i always get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:695)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:2016)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

I have been trying to find out what is wrong many hours, but without success.
I saw many questions, but :
[this is useless because in function cannot be transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380074/parameter-number-2-is-not-an-out-parameter)

[this is useless because when i use named parameter NullPointerEx is throwed(why??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183344/why-java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-number-x-is-not-an-out-parameter?lq=1)

[this is useless because procedure exists, and dont throw any exception when i use only IN param, but with INOUT or OUT is throwed mentioned exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240093/parameter-number-x-is-not-an-out-parameter?rq=1)

[this is useless because i cant see any obvious mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581950/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-number-2-is-not-an-out-parameter)

[this is useless because update JDBC connector didnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336557/getting-out-parameter-from-mysql-stored-procedure-in-java?rq=1)

So my question is simple : Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I would try two things: (1) Use `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test_database` connection string, and remove the call of `execute("USE test_database")`. (2) Swap `setInt` and `registerOutParameter` lines.

Comment: To add to @dasblinkenlight's suggestions: perhaps try .execute() instead of .executeQuery(). The guides I skimmed use .execute() but I'm not sure it relates to your error, but could be a future error you'll run into.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh man, you made my day! Thank you. Can i ask you, add your comment as answer. I will accept it as the best answer. And if you know what is diffrence between "USE database_name;" statement and determine database name in URL, please write it to answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try two things:

1. Use `"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test_database"` connection string, and remove the call of `execute("USE test_database")`
2. Swap `setInt` and `registerOutParameter` lines.

In general, executing `USE test_database` should be fine, but [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) explicitly cautions agains using it:

> Always use the `Connection.setCatalog()` method to specify the desired database in JDBC applications, rather than the `USE database` statement.

Although the context is slightly different, it appears that the same advise applies to your situation as well.